# Android : uploading app for internal team not for all users

Tags: android, apk

we have an android application that is used for internal team management.I awnt to upload it to playstore.But few questions here,
Should i upload it as alpha or beta and send link to the users
Should i upload it on production

The apk is not of any use to the users , it is just for internal team
We want to upload it to playstore and not on any server.

Comment: See: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: I am confused between uploading it as test or production..If i upload it as test then i have to add users as they come,(int the company) in the testers list and need to share the url with each and every user..

Comment: If you want to use the Play Store it could be as a 'closed test' where you manage users by by email address, Google Groups, or Google+ Communities. The alternative is to enroll in a Enterprise Mobile Management (EMM) and set that up as a Google Play Publisher: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en Or you host the APK yourself (with internal team enabling third-party apps setting) or if the backend's authentication can handle a public store release do make it a public app.

Comment: okays thanks a lot...